# How to edit coherent_pool setting via cmdline.txt

Tags: pi-3, usb, cmdline.txt

I have a problem with connecting multiple USB devices to a RPI3B+. I found this solution which suggests that setting coherent_pool=2M in cmdline.txt resolves the issue:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4008#issuecomment-765554558

The conclusion is:

> "After some searching the solution was simple: Adding coherent_pool=2M
> to cmdline.txt allows the use of all 48 ports on the Rpi3B+."

However when I add coherent_pool=2M to /boot/cmdline.txt it seems to be overridden somewhere.

When I look in dmesg the Kernel cmdline still says coherent_pool=1M at the start, as does cat /proc/cmdline.

I found reports that a bug in an old version of Raspbian meant that the incorrect boot partition was mounted, however this doesn't seem to be my case because I can see my coherent_pool=2M in dmesg and /proc/cmdline, it just doesn't seem to have had any effect, so I'm assuming that the 1M setting that appears before it is being parsed first and mine is being ignored.

Where is that 1M setting originating and how can I override it?

Comment: *"Where is that 1M setting originating and how can I override it?"* -> Do you have any reason to believe you have not, besides the fact that it presumably did not solve your problem?  Qv. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689802/25985  ...I also looked around quickly to see if there is a way to find what `coherent_pool` is actually set to (eg. via sysfs) but found nothing.

Comment: Good catch, you're correct that I have no information other than "It's not fixed like the guy said it would be". I guess based on your link there that it is changing the coherent pool, but that it hasn't fixed the problem. I also found that this is actually a 3B not a 3B+ so perhaps that's why it's not fixed in my case. Thanks!